# How to all Screen Support Any Version in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to all screen support in all screen size but small device not display screen very well my Main Layout in Below.And Custom row Layout Below.And i used Screen Support in Manifest file add.How to solve it>

Mainlayout xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_lay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/greybackground" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/all_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/accepted_all"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/accepted_all"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
            android:background="@drawable/list" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accepted_all"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/menu_download_video"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/not_shown"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/accepted_all"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/accepted_all"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dip"
           android:background="@drawable/download1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <com.example.testhopequeue.TextProgressBarFree
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/memory_indicator_progress" 
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/occupiedSpace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freeSpace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.example.testhopequeue.TextProgressBarReq
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/reqmemory_indicator_progress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/occupiedSpace1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/occupiedSpace"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freeSpace1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/freeSpace"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i add Custom row Add in Scroll view in XML File Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/colImgPath"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/download1"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.example.testhopequeue.TextProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="180dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:max="100"
            android:maxHeight="50dip"
            android:maxWidth="50dip"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to read this documenation
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

or this article "Designing for Multiple Screens"

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html